# How can I hide the entire "Shipping Details" block on the admin side of Woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

My Woocommerce store has virtual products that don't require shipping. I have disabled the shipping options from the customer on checkout, but now I want to hide it on the backend as well.

When viewing orders on the admin side, I have 3 columns: General Details, Billing Details and Shipping Details. I want to remove the Shipping Details in the third column so that later I can add some custom fields there instead.

I've tried using

```php
remove_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_shipping_fields', 'filter_woocommerce_admin_shipping_fields'  );
```

but that doesn't change anything on the backend.

I could probably do it with some deeply complicated CSS and display:none, but I'd rather just remove it programmatically, like with a remove_filter or something.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no "clean" solution for what you are asking.

However, you can manually delete this block by editing woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-meta-box-order-data.php line 315-397.

Comment: Thanks - I'd rather just leave it then. I prefer not to edit core files in plugins as you only lose the changes you make on the next upgrade.

Comment: Editing core files should *NEVER EVER* be suggested

Comment: @kanlukasz You are right, and it breaks update compatibility. This is now a 5years old response and obviously I would have done it in a different way now. I think that the css only solution is a bit weak since the html remains unchanged. What would you suggest ?.

Answer (score 1):

Or try this

```
add_action( 'init', 'hide_shipping_details' );
function hide_shipping_details() { 
    if( is_admin()) { 
       echo '<style> #fieldset-shipping{ display: none !important;} </style>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this woocommerce filter:

```php
//Hide Shippping and Billing form users backend
add_filter( 'woocommerce_customer_meta_fields', 'hide_shipping_billing' );
function hide_shipping_billing( $show_fields ) {
    unset( $show_fields['shipping'] );
    unset( $show_fields['billing'] );
    return $show_fields;
}
```

Comment: I'd guess that only affects the user profile page though, not the checkout?